# HTML 5 video cannot play on Firefox 7

Tags: html, firefox, html5-video

I want to embed a video in the webpage, I use the following code:

```
<!-- Video Section-->
<video controls="controls" width="640px">
    <source src="media/videos/video.mp4"  type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
    <source src="media/videos/video.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'/>
    <source src="media/videos/video.ogv"  type='application/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'/>
</video>
```

So I can play this video on Safari, Chrome, but cannot on Firefox. I think Firefox support both `ogg` and `webm` video, so I don't know what's the problem. I only saw a gray block with a cross mark inside.

p.s. I used to use `type='video/ogg'`, it didn't work, so I change to this `type='application/ogg'` based on googled suggestions, but this still doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably server settings. if you're on apache, check your mime.types file and see if or set these
AddType video/ogg .ogm
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/ogg .ogg

Comment: So I only have the permissions for my directory on server, I don't have the access to server configurations, how can i do this? Thanks

Comment: Also, I know firefox 4+ also supports webm, so i did a test this afternoon, i removed the line <source src="media/videos/video.ogv"  type='application/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'/> but still, firefox cannot play the video.